# Create drop menu when click on a span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a drop menu to appear when the user clicks on a span element and then the menu to disappear when user moves the mouse out of the menu. I tried with js but i can't do what i want.Is this possible? Here's my code(i use the helpbatch function to transform uppercase letters in lowercase and i know that i could do it in another way):

```js
function batch() {
  var projects = ["Batch Script Tutorial", "Manage your PC", "Yahoo joke"];
  var text = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    text += "<a href='http://www.programming-multilang.tk/p/" + helpbatch(i, projects) + ".html'>" + projects[i] + "</a>" + '<hr style="border-color: rgb(61, 34, 126)">';
  }
  document.getElementById("showbatch").style.opacity = "1";
  document.getElementById("batch").style.float = "left";

  document.getElementById("showbatch").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.getElementById("showbatch").innerHTML = text;
}

function helpbatch(vari, storage) {
  var dic = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "Y", "Z", "W", "X"];
  var dicmic = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "y", "z", "w", "d"];

  var a = storage[vari].split(" ");
  var fin = "";
  var spl = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var ans = "";
    spl = a[i].split("");

    for (j = 0; j < spl.length; j++) {
      var help = 0;
      for (m = 0; m < dic.length; m++) {
        if (spl[j] === dic[m]) {
          ans += dicmic[m];
        } else {
          help++;
        }
      }
      if (help === 26) {
        ans += spl[j];
      }
    }
    if (i < a.length - 1) {
      fin += ans + "-";
    } else {
      fin += ans;
    }
  }
  return fin;
}






function batchleave(x) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    x++;
    document.getElementById("showbatch").style.opacity = "0." + (10 - x);
    if (10 - x === 0) {
      document.getElementById("showbatch").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("batch").style.float = "none";
    }
    if (x < 10) {
      batchleave(x);
    }
  }, 30);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="project" id="batch" onclick="batch()" title="Press to see the projects">Projects</span>
</div>
<div>
  <div onmouseleave="batchleave(0)" id="showbatch" style="background-color: #300a62; box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px black; color: aliceblue; display: none; line-height: 1.5; padding: 10px; position: absolute; z-index: 10;">
  </div>
```

Comment: What do u want? Drop menu is there??

Comment: I want a drop menu that appears when the user clicks the button(or div ,etc.) and then when the user leaves the menu to dissappear

Comment: Currently i'm able to see your drop menu when i run your code snippet

Comment: I think it would be better if i would done it with ul(sorry for mistakes;this is not my original language)

Comment: Yes but if you click the projects span and you move the mouse outside the menu will stay like that

Comment: Please clarify edit your post and clarify your requirment

Comment: No it's working if u re moving outside

Comment: Press the "Project" button.Ok? Now move the mouse out(down the web page if you want).The menu didn't disappear!(of course because i don't know how to do that)I want to disappear!(look at the code!)

Comment: it dissappears, what browser are you using?

Comment: I use chrome.Look at the code ,please.Press the "Project " button(and leave the mouse on it!) and then take the mouse and move it for example in top left corner of this web page(so you won't tuch the menu that just appeared!) .You will see that the menu will not disappear.